# getEnclosingMethod returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, methods, testng, assertion

Inside TestNG test method, I am using this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() to get the current method name but it gives failure exception as  java.lang.NullPointerException

I am unsure, what would be the problem?

```
Assert.assertEquals(this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName(), testcaseName);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be duplicate, i am calling getClass methods on the class itself,so not sure why it's throwing the exception. I'll have a look at the link though.

Comment: It's pretty similar, in your example `getEnclosingMethod()` is `null` so `getName()`throws the exception.

Comment: I've added  @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeTestMethod(Method testMethod){
      log4j.info("Before Testmethod: " + testMethod.getName());   
      testName = testMethod.getName();
    }          This fixed the problem.